# Is Thomas rotation compatible with equivalence principle?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, equivalence-principle

I have designed a thought experiment for which I cannot find a clear solution:

An infinitesimal laser gun and a point target both move with a velocity $v$ towards a deep rhomboidal hole dug in the ground. From the viewpoint of observer $A$ at rest with respect to the hole, the laser gun would first fall into the hole with a uniform G-acceleration in the $z$-direction (perpendicular to the page), and after a delay, the target would also fall into it undergoing similar gravitation. [See Figure-(a)] However, $A$ claims that the mentioned delay upsets the straight alignment between the laser gun and target, and thus if the laser gun emits a photon whenever during the fall, it will never reach the point target. (The target lags the laser gun in the $z$-direction)

Now assume that observer $B$ with a constant velocity $u$ approaches the hole in the $y$-direction. If the initial angle of the hole is intended to be $\theta_0=tan^{-1} (c^2/uv)$, observer $B$ claims that the alignment of the laser gun and target is parallel to side $EF$ of the hole. Applying two successive boosts (Thomas rotation angle), the mentioned alignment is, indeed, rotated at an angle $\phi=tan^{-1} (\alpha_u c^2/uv)$ from the standpoint of $B$, where $\alpha_u=\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$. In this special case, $B$ observes that the laser gun and the target would simultaneously reach side $EF$ and fall into the hole keeping their initial alignment. [See Figure-(b)]

[image]

If $B$ tends to use equivalence principle, he can claim that if the laser gun emits a photon whenever after the fall, the photon will certainly hit the point target!

Where is the problem?

Comment: Something doesn't add up here, because by your formulas, for stationary B ($u=0$), we have that $\alpha_u=1$ and $\theta_0=\phi$, which I'm pretty sure is not what you want.

Comment: No, it's not what I want. Consider a value other than zero for $u$ please. Moreover, for $u=0$ we have $\theta_0=\phi=\pi/2$ which resolves the problem.

Comment: The beam curves.

Comment: @stuffu, It is not about the path of light but rather the alignment of the laser gun and target. It seems that if this alignment is parallel to $y$-direction, the emitted photon will always reach the target whenever after the fall, however, $A$ claims that the alignment is no longer parallel to $y$ due to the mentioned delay.

Comment: So bending of the beam is not the solution. Well then my next guess is that if the laser gun hits the target while there is a gravity field, then it misses the target if the field suddenly disappears. Now a bent beam becomes a straight one.